# JS Promises: Why is it that you can't set code to execute after the callback of setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise, asynchronous-javascript

I'm reading [this article](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) on promise chaining in Javascript, and am confused about the section where it says `how can we do something after the avatar has finished showing and gets removed? For instance, we’d like to show a form for editing that user or something else. As of now, there’s no way.`

Is the reason that we can't do something after the image gets removed that `img.remove()` doesn't return a promise? Or is it that `setTimeout` doesn't return anything after its callback is finished?

Comment: `you can't set code to execute after the callback of setTimeout?` because it runs asynchronously - do what you need inside the callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it's saying is that, by using the code in the example:

```
setTimeout(() => img.remove(), 3000); // (*)
```

Using that code exactly, you can't detect when the image gets removed and do something when it occurs - its asynchronous removal is disconnected from the outer Promise chain.

The article's recommendation to fix it is to have the constructed Promise resolve when `.remove()` is called:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  img.remove();
  resolve(githubUser);
}, 3000);
```

Or you could put more code inside the `setTimeout` to run exactly when the image gets removed.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  img.remove();
  console.log('removed');
}, 3000);
```

If you don't do either of the above, and instead have *just* the `setTimeout(() => img.remove(), 3000);`, the asynchronous action that occurs after 3 seconds *can't* do anything except remove the image - which is usually a mistake. For example, if you wanted to chain another `.then` onto it which runs when the image gets removed, and the image needs to be removed after 3 seconds

```
.then(() => {
  // what logic to put in here to ensure next .then runs after 3 seconds?
  setTimeout(() => {
    img.remove();
  }, 3000);
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('image removed');
});
```

When inside a `.then`, to have the next `.then` run after a delay, you *must* return a Promise from the above `.then`, and that Promise must resolve after the delay is over.

```
.then(() => {
  // what logic to put in here to ensure next .then runs after 3 seconds?
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      img.remove();
    }, 3000);
  });
.then(() => {
  console.log('image removed');
});
```

If you don't return a Promise from the upper `.then`, or if you don't return anything at all, the lower `.then` will run immediately, as soon as the upper `.then` finishes, which you don't want.